# How do I add up the values of multiple divs in jQuery and append the final sum to another div?

Tags: jquery, html

My markup looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="box">
    <div class="box_content">
        <div class="box_price">180</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="box_content">
        <div class="box_price">230</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="box_content">
        <div class="box_price">120</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="cost"></div>
```

The number of boxes is not static and their price can be any value. How do I use jQuery to make the div "cost" display the sum of all "box_price" divs?

Comment: when you say any value, you mean integer only? or floats are possible also? what about thousand separator?

Comment: I mean only integer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `each()` to iterate through your elements.

```
var total = 0;
$('.box > .box_content > .box_price').each(function(){
  total += parseInt($(this).text());
});
```

Append it to the container

```
$('.container').append("<div class='sum'>Total : "+total+"</div>");
```

```js
var total =0;
$('.box > .box_content > .box_price').each(function(){
  total += parseInt($(this).text());
});
$('.container').append("<div class='sum'>Total : "+total+"</div>");
console.log(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="box">
    <div class="box_content">
        <div class="box_price">180</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="box_content">
        <div class="box_price">230</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="box_content">
        <div class="box_price">120</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works fine. I have a question. How do I target .box_price specifically inside .container? I have .box cloned into .container from another place on the same page.

Comment: Try something like `$('.container > .box_price').each`

Comment: This is excellent. Still helpful 6 years later. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sum = 0;

$(".box_price").each(function(){

    sum += parseInt($(this).html());

});

$('#cost').html(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `each()` iterator for traverse through every element.

Here is the fiddle

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sudhanshu_a3logics/k4keLjqq/1/)

Comment: what's the meaning of posting an identical answer ?

Comment: i see. but its not identical "technically". as you can see you are `appending` and am using `html`